# Hide dynamically created UILabels in IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have declared UILabel in ViewController first like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel;
```

Then I have created label in a loop:

```
//creating answer labels
    i = 0;
    int y=200;
    while (i < numberOfAnswers) {
        UILabel *answerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, y, 300, 20)];
        answerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", questionBank[randomQuestionNumber][1][i][0],questionBank[randomQuestionNumber][1][i][1]];
        answerLabel.hidden=NO;
        [self.view addSubview:answerLabel];
    i++;
    y = y + 20;
    }
```

In the IBAction I have this but it doesn't work. Any ideas where the mistakes is?

```
- (IBAction)nextQuestion:(id)sender {
    //hiding labels
    self.answerLabel.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest create one view and add those label in this view... now when you want to hide, just hide this view (so that you dont have to play with all 200 labels)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest first create view and then add those labels in this view.

Now when you need to hide, just hide this view.

Hope this answer.

---

For what you are doing, it is lengthy way. First white creating label you have to set tag. Then for hiding, again get label by tag and then hide accordingly.

Comment: is there any way i can set a tag for the label in this loop?

Comment: @DomasfromUK : `answerLabel.tag = i;`. But I would suggest create view and for hide, hide view...

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains lots of issues.

First of all, when you are talking about multiple outlets,  in the declaration it should be outletCollection like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *answerLabels;
```

Again, as you are creating your labels dynamically, you just can't add them in your `IBOuletCollection`.

@FahimParkar is suggesting a good approach. But as you might need to work with individual labels, you might use following approach..

First declare an array of labels like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *answerLabels;
```

Now when you are creating the label, alloc your array & add new labels in it like this:

```
i = 0;
    int y=200;
self.answerLabels= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
    while (i < numberOfAnswers) {
        UILabel *answerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, y, 300, 20)];
        answerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", questionBank[randomQuestionNumber][1][i][0],questionBank[randomQuestionNumber][1][i][1]];
        answerLabel.hidden=NO;
        [self.view addSubview:answerLabel];
[self.answerLabels addObject:answerLabel]
    i++;
    y = y + 20;
    }
```

Now when you want to hide a particular label, you can do this by referring anyone of these three:

1. Array index.
2. labelText.
3. add tag for your label as suggested by Fahim & refer to it.. :)

Let me know if more info needed.. :)

Comment: I have used your code provided, but when I try to compile it crashes. http://s16.postimg.org/xe9vnjkkl/Screen_Shot_2014_02_23_at_09_49_25.png

Comment: @DomasfromUK.. Where is it crashing? the image you have shared is the breakpoint you have kept.

Comment: i have commented out the code and it still crashes.. i haven't altered any code before that. http://s28.postimg.org/615le16sd/Screen_Shot_2014_02_23_at_10_03_42.png

Comment: how to have a look where is it crashing?

Comment: @DomasfromUK.. Its not crashing my dear.. can you see a blue arrow in the screen? that is a breakpoint.. press ctrl+cmd+y & it will pass through it.. better remove the breakpoint by dragging it away from the place.  (blue pointer in line 131. drag it away from the place & make it disappear. then press ctrl+cmd+Y)